# Spectral sequences in algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, fibre-bundles

What books/articles do you recommend for learning spectral sequences? I am interested in their applications to algebraic topology, particularly to understand the homology of fibre bundles. I have a good backgroud on differential geometry and a reasonable background on modules and algebras.

Comment: The Serre spectral sequence is the starter for most people, as far as I know.  I found Spanier to be a good reference, but likely there are better and more modern references now.

Comment: I think Hatcher has some good notes.

Comment: Mosher and Tangora is a good (but perhaps old-fashioned) way to get started with the Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: I really like homotopical topology by fomenko and fuchs

Comment: Relevant questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45036/spectral-sequences-opening-the-black-box-slowly-with-an-example/, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23297/simple-examples-for-the-use-of-spectral-sequences, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22188/introductory-book-on-spectral-sequences

Answer (score 6):

My favourite reference for understanding spectral sequences is

> Boardman, J. Michael. "Conditionally convergent spectral sequences." *Contemporary Mathematics* 239 (1999): 49-84 ([pdf](https://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Boardman/ccspseq.pdf)).

I don't think I really understood a spectral sequence before reading it. After that, examples examples examples. The Serre spectral sequence is a good place to start (and Serre's original paper not the worst place to learn it).

Answer (score 5):

The article by Timothy Chow, "You Could Have Invented Spectral Sequences", *Notices of the AMS* **53** 2006 pp. 15-19 ([pdf](https://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-chow.pdf)) is a start.

Given your background and interests, you could try John McCleary's *A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences*, (Cambridge, 2001) doi:[10.1017/CBO9780511626289](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511626289).

More at the following question: [Spectral Sequences reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165466/spectral-sequences-reference).

Comment: Doug Ravenel "accidentally" put his personal copy of the pdf of McCleary's book on an internet-facing location on his computer...

Answer (score 4):

I have learnt it from Mosher and Tangora. But, perhaps John McCleary’s book is a reference to be mentioned.